# How to make admin account in windows?

Tags: c#

I can add a guest user using the following code

```
DirectoryEntry AD = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" +
                                Environment.MachineName + ",computer");
            DirectoryEntry NewUser = AD.Children.Add("TestUser1", "user");
            NewUser.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { "password" });
            NewUser.Invoke("Put", new object[] { "Description", "Test User from .NET" });
            NewUser.CommitChanges();
            DirectoryEntry grp;

            grp = AD.Children.Find("Guests", "group");
            if (grp != null) { grp.Invoke("Add", new object[] { NewUser.Path.ToString() }); }
            Console.WriteLine("Account Created Successfully...");
            Console.ReadLine();
```

what changes should I change to make it as a Administrator user/standard User?

Comment: `grp = AD.Children.Find("Guests", "group");` can't you put an administrator group there instead of guests? Just guessing here

Comment: @EpicKip he has already mentioned that this code is for `Guest` account

Comment: @Nobody That's why he's asking what to change, it says guests so maybe change it to administrators or something...

Comment: Found [this solution](https://forums.asp.net/t/1057619.aspx?How+do+we+create+a+user+with+admin+rights+in+C+using+DirectoryEntry) for you, Vishnu, @EpicKip  [this](https://forums.asp.net/t/1057619.aspx?How+do+we+create+a+user+with+admin+rights+in+C+using+DirectoryEntry) might help the OP

Comment: @Nobody The solution is exactly what i said (`grp = dirEntry.Children.Find("Administrators", "group");`) just administrators instead of guests

Comment: @EpicKip Yes indeed!

Comment: thanks... please post it as an answer